# Tabular editing of feature layer in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: web-mapping, editing, arcgis-online, feature-service

I have a point feature layer in AGOL that contains the locations, station names, and a bunch of other metadata attributes (when the site was created, whether or not it's active, etc.)

Is there a good way to allow selected editors to edit the data in the attribute table without going through a pop-up?

The ideal scenario would be to join the point locations with a google sheet containing the attributes. I know that this can be done by publishing a google sheet csv to web, but those can't be saved as an item in AGOL, and I want to use this layer in multiple maps.

I am also considering ArcGIS Pro and Desktop for editing, but the users that need to edit have no GIS experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit tabular data in ArcGIS Online under the new item details page released this summer. So if your feature layer is an item in ArcGIS Online, open the item details and go to the data tab and you will be able to edit the data in the table. This also supports editing related records. *Note this does not support creating new records only editing existing.